# OSX Server guest within VirtualBox ... where do I get the ISO

Tags: macos, osx-server, virtualization, virtualbox, iso

I'm trying to do things legit and purchased a copy of OSX Server to go along with my OSX install.  I am running a MacBook Pro with Mountain Lion... so I'm OK from a hardware perspective.

Now I'm trying to install OSX onto virtual box (client or server) but can't locate a suitable ISO to boot from.  My MAC didn't come with one and want to use legitimate software (nothing hacky) to get it working.

Is hackboot required to make this work?  I'd like to limit the sources I get my software from.

Comment: I second the idea of not getting an ISO from anyone - but instead getting a recipe for an ISO. The real problem is virtual box - they have been cranky about supporting OS X as a guest OS even though the licensing terms to allow virtualization of all versions of OS X on Mac hardware has been around since July 2011. (And Server was allowed to be virtualized before Lion) You might be better off with VMWare or Parallels than Virtual Box.

Comment: @bmike Even with VMWare or Parallels, won't I need an installation ISO?

Comment: They have imaging tools to image a new install from an external drive - it's much easier to just run the Lion installer or Mountain Lion ["Install OS X ESD"](https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com/search.html?query=install+esd). It's much faster to use any old USB drive for imaging / installing a clean OS than messing with making an ISO. OS X virtualization is easy once you get how to image a drive and understand the tools for making/converting virtual drives on your VM of choice.